# Constants for "fulfilled" and "rejected" for nodejs Promise.allSettled

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I've recently been using [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) to run async methods in parallel and collect the successful/failed results.

I usually do something like:

```js
const results = await Promise.allSettled([doSomething(), doSomethingElse()]);
const happy = results.filter((result) => result.status === "fulfilled").map((result) => result.value);
const sad = results.filter((result) => result.status === "rejected").map((result) => result.reason);
```

I wondered if there are any constants for the strings `"fulfilled"` and `"rejected"`?

Comment: No. Such "constants" do not exist - why would they be at all useful?

Comment: seems `status` is part of api response

Comment: @brk ... [Promise.allSettled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) - yes ... the results all have `status` then either `value` or `reason` depending on `status` - nothing to do with OP's question though ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: think about it ... if such a constant existed, it would be a property of `Promise` ... so instead of `result.status === "fulfilled"` you'd write `result.status === Promise.FULFILLED` - you're not saving anything, just typing more - it makes a bit of sense say with `XMLHttpRequest.DONE` because that's more descriptive than `4` :p

Comment: @JaromandaX just feels a little neater to test against a constant rather than a string :) it doesn't matter much in the grand scheme of things but I was curious to see if anyone knows of any... Feels like there should be a `Promise.FULFILLED`

Comment: As much as people warn against it ... nothing stopping you from doing `Object.defineProperty(Promise, 'FULFILLED', { get() { return 'fulfilled'}})` in your code :p - or `Object.defineProperty(Promise, 'FULFILLED', { get: () => 'fulfilled'})` for that matter

Comment: @JaromandaX haha true I suppose so!